# Springboot stomp websocket does not find jakarta.websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, websocket

I am moving my first steps in developing a websocket stomp client and server in java with Springboot framework, using Intellij and Gradle. I successfully built a working example. Now I am changing the code to use the java module system but get the following exception when starting the server application

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: jakarta/websocket/Endpoint
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.4/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.4/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.0.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.0.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.0.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.0.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.0.2/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.chesolver.tl.wsserverdue/com.chesolver.tl.example1.server.MessagingStompWebsocketApplication.main(MessagingStompWebsocketApplication.java:10) ~[wsserver-plain.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: jakarta/websocket/Endpoint
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: jakarta/websocket/Endpoint

    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@6.0.4/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/websocket/Endpoint
```

so the cause is that `jakarta.websocket` is not found. Probably this is a depedency problem but I am not sure about the reason, the code was working before modularization and I would expect that `spring-boot-starter-websocket` would bring jakarta into the game. Indeed I get similar exceptions also for the client application.

This is my `buil.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-core'
    implementation 'org.webjars:sockjs-client:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.webjars:stomp-websocket:2.3.3'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.7'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.1.1-1'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation project(':core')
}
```

Thanks, any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's your problem, but I was facing a similar issue where `jakarta.websocket.Endpoint` was not found.

I was using the dependency `jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-api`, and I found out that [starting from 2.1.0](https://github.com/jakartaee/websocket/blob/ca41696e7d7a48d4f74d1546e0f006a2e82d657d/spec/src/main/asciidoc/WebSocket.adoc#a1-changes-between-21-and-20) that library doesn't include the "client" classes anymore (it says it doesn't have a "copy" anymore, but I guess you can't even get the classes from there) So I had to include a dependency to `jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-client-api` as well, to have that `Endpoint` class available.